# Deploying Database To SQL Azure Error

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to publish a website to Azure, The publish settings were carefully reviewed, the files get published but the database is not, I'm getting this error.

> Error 1   Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete an operation
>   with the specified provider ("dbFullSql") when connecting using the
>   Web Management Service. This can occur if the server administrator has
>   not authorized the user for this operation. dbFullSql
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178034   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_DBFULLSQL.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try the suggestions at the link?

Comment: Yes, But It didn't work